# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CustomCanvas'

Tags: flutter

WhenEver I am trying to create a shorebird apk, it fails and give such error:

```
✗ Failed to build: ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.8/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/visible_descriptors/render_custom_paint_descriptor.dart:66:30: Error: The method 'CustomCanvas' isn't defined for the class 'RenderCustomPaintDescriptor'.
 - 'RenderCustomPaintDescriptor' is from 'package:flutter_smartlook/wireframe/element_descriptors/visible_descriptors/render_custom_paint_descriptor.dart' ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.8/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/visible_descriptors/render_custom_paint_descriptor.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CustomCanvas'.
      final Canvas _canvas = CustomCanvas(pictureRecorder, (rect, color) {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/admin/.shorebird/bin/cache/flutter/0f62afa7ad2eaa2fa44ff28278d6c6eaf81f327e/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1319

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command '/Users/admin/.shorebird/bin/cache/flutter/0f62afa7ad2eaa2fa44ff28278d6c6eaf81f327e/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
 (37.7s)
```

I have tried to run

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`
`flutter pub upgrade`

But still facing this error.

This is my smartlook version that I am using:`flutter_smartlook: ^4.1.8-flutter3.13.0`
This issue is related to smartlook.